# Create a table cell with automatic newline and word splitting

Tags: tables, line-breaking, hyphenation

I'm trying to create a table similar to:

```
_______________________________________________________
      Dataset name    |       Example of text         |
______________________________________________________|
      DatasetName1    |This is an example and I like t|
                      |hat text goes newline and word |
                      |splitting is forced http://exam|
                      |ple/newlinesandwords.com       |
______________________________________________________|
      DatasetName2    |yesIliketowritelotofthingswithn|
                      |ospacesatall                   | 
... and so on
```

Vertical lines are only for visualization convenience, I prefer the table without them.
I also like to  have monospace characters inside the second column, I have used texttt for this.
I have tried with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{PROVA}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
      \centering
      \caption{Datasets}
      \label{my-label}
      \begin{tabular}{l | p{0.4\textwidth} |}
      \toprule
      Dataset name & Example of Text \\ \midrule
      DatasetName1  & \texttt{This is an example and I like that text goes newline and word splitting is forced http://example/newlinesandwords.com} \\ \midrule
      DatasetName2  & \texttt{yesIliketowritelotofthingswithnospacesatall} \\ \midrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But the long words simply ignores the table boundaries and go out (this is an example of the obtained behaviour):

---

```
      Dataset name    |       Example of text         |
______________________________________________________|
      DatasetName1    |This is an example and I like  |
                      |that text goes newline and word|
                      |splitting is forced            |
                      |http://example/newlinesandwords.com       
______________________________________________________|
      DatasetName2    |yesIliketowritelotofthingswithnospacesatall                |
```

How do I activate word-breaking with no hyphenation for these table cells?
Any tip is appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Please provide complete small document starting with `\documentclass{...} and ending with `end{document}`. Do you load `babel` package?

Comment: When I complete your code in the obvious way, it compiles without error and with no word going beyond the boundary of the table. We need an example which we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yoou didn't provide complete document as I ask you. Also you didn't say anything if you use `babel`, which support hyphenation. And for sure, for `\texttt{yesIliketowritelotofthingswithnospacesatall}` doesn't exist hyphenation pattern, i.e. for this "word" you need insert hyphenation points manualy.

Comment: If you want URLs split in this way, use `url` and `\url{<whatever>}`. If you want anything else split in this way, please explain what you are really trying to do as I'm assuming you aren't trying to split arbitrary text at arbitrary points or avoid the use of hyphens when slitting ordinary words.

Comment: @Zarko I'm sorry about being late, I'll provide further details in few hours. I'll fix my example in order to better fit the case. I only need few hours. I have not had time to manage things in the last 12 hours. Thank you for the assistance and replying, I'll reply to your message ASAP.

Comment: @cfr thanks for pointing out, it is my fault, I created an example by modifying the real code (there was data inside that I cannot publish at the moment). I have fixed the code (smaller column width) and added vertical lines in order to better notice the behaviour. I also converted to a fully working example.

Comment: Does that really give you the error you report?

Comment: Thanks, that error was in the original code, I'll update the post accordingly.

Comment: @Zarko In the original document I have also loaded the babel package. The problem is that inside the cell there may be text that is not composed by english or italian words but there are also product codes, phone numbers, urls and so on, this is the reason I was looking to a way to split the text in arbitrary point. I have used the keyword "hypenation" because I have wrongly supposed that my goal  may be accomplished with the same tools used for hypenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX doesn't do line breaking within words, except at hyphenation points. So you must insert a possible break point between each two characters. To do this with a macro is not easy. However, the `soul` package has an (internal) macro that can do it and is used for its commands like `\so` and `\ul`. So we can use that to build a command to insert the line break points.

```
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\breakwords{%
    \SOUL@setup
    \def\SOUL@everyexhyphen##1{##1\linebreak[1]}%
    \def\SOUL@everytoken{\the\SOUL@token\linebreak[1]}%
    \SOUL@}
\makeatother

  \begin{tabular}{l p{0.4\textwidth}}
  \toprule
  Dataset name & Example of Text \\ \midrule
  DatasetName1  & \texttt{\breakwords{This is an example and I like that text goes newline and word splitting is forced http://example/newlinesandwords.com}} \\ \midrule
  DatasetName2  & \texttt{\breakwords{yesIliketowritelotofthingswithnospacesatall}} \\ \midrule
  \end{tabular}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I meant line breaking at any place. Corrected in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Piet van Oostrum, your solution is exactly what I was looking for. I have tried in different tables and worked like a charm